# Word meaning "has many similar forms"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, puns

I'm looking for one word (or a variety of words) that imply ambiguity through synonymous meaning.

> "Do you have that in large?"
>
> "No sir, we only have it in big, great, impressive, grand, and
>   king-sized"

The closest I have are "double-entendre" and "heteronym", but neither is quite right: double-entendre tends to relate to smutty puns, and heteronymic(?) words have to be spelled the same.

Comment: Your question seems to be looking for a word that has many meanings, but your example is a meaning that has many ways to say it. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Jeremy relating to words that have many forms that have similar/identical meanings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [polymorph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polymorph) word.
And from google's definition:

```
polymorph(s) - ˈpɒlɪmɔːf/
an organism or inorganic object or material which takes various forms.
```

This is also used in programming, for polymorphism, particularly object-oriented programming. A very beautiful word, if i have to say.

Comment: Shameless self-congratulatory upvote! ;) Thank you.

Comment: @Sakatox I think equivoque might also fit the bill

Comment: Absolutely agree! I learned a new word today, only "complaint" i could muster up is the dictionary "smell" of it. Probably an occupational bias, but i do hear more polymorphism than equivoqueness.

Answer (score 2):

**No !** Sorry folks to disappoint your warmest enthusiasm...

So far *poly**morph*** concern the **form**, the **shape** (as says the previous definition !) that word is not the one expected...

This one should be : **POLYSEMY** (where *-semy* means sense/meaning)